# Why is Gradient Checking Slow For Back Propagation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, numerical-methods, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I recently learned the algorithm "Gradient Checking" for making sure the derivatives of my Neural Network's Back Propagation are calculated properly.

[The course from which I have learned](https://www.coursera.org/learn/deep-neural-network/home/welcome), and many other sources such as [this one](https://imaddabbura.github.io/blog/machine%20learning/deep%20learning/2018/04/08/coding-neural-network-gradient-checking.html), claim it to be much slower than calculating derivatives, but I can't seem to find anywhere that explains WHY.

So, why is gradient checking slower than calculating the derivative directly?

How much slower is it?

Comment: As a theoretical question, this belongs on either one of [stats.se], [datascience.se], or [ai.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing in back-propagation is the backwards mode of automatic/algorithmic differentiation for a function that has a very large number `N` of inputs and only one output. The "inputs" here mean chiefly the real-number parameters of the nodes of the neural nets, possibly also the input variables of the net.

In the backwards mode you compute the derivatives of all inputs in one pass through the chain of operations. This has the cost of about 3 function evaluations plus the organizational overhead to execute the operations chain backwards and store and access the intermediate results.

In the forward mode for the same situation, which you use for the "gradient checking", independent of if you push forward the AD derivatives or compute divided differences, you will need to compute each derivative individually. The total cost of that is about `2*N` function evaluations.

And as `N` is large, `2*N` is much larger than 3.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the expensive part was the activation of the cost function `J(x)`. I was counting its activation as a single operation.

Do you have some estimate (as a function of N) for the "organizational overhead" computations?

Also, where did the number 3 come from? As far as I can tell, for back propagation, you don't need even a single activation of the cost function `J`.

Comment: As you keep all intermediate results in the network structure, and the function itself is computed as a network, the cost of the overhead should be the same as the cost during the forward evaluation. The 3 comes essentially from the analysis of the multiplication as elementary step. In the derivative formula you get 2 additional multiplications, turning one operation in the function evaluation into 3 (or 2 additional) for the derivative. Addition is counted as negligible relative to multiplication, or the analysis is done in FMA. The other elementary operations have smaller factors.